# Drupal: Unable to create directory 'temporary://update-extraction/'

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

When I try to install a module on a **drupal 7.37** version I get following message:

```
 Unable to create directory 'temporary://update-extraction-9b760e0c/.
```

In the Configuration->Media->File System I have the ./path/to/tmp folder with 777 permissions

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the file path in `Configuration > File System > Temporary` Directory to `home/youUserName/tmp`

Comment: I am using mac and it's not working with this location /Users/mboeckle/tmp/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the temp folder is owned by the OS. Try to set the temp path to relative path.

> sites/default/files/tmp

No slashes at the beginning.

Comment: weird I am still getting the message - but the directory is created

Comment: What is the value of the temp directory textfield in `Configuration->Media->File System` ?

Comment: as you recommended "sites/default/files/tmp" - get this error message "Unable to create directory" when I try to install a module through the URL

Comment: I also think this is a apache - drupal upload problem. I get this message: The specified file temporary://fileVFLtvg could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured - when drupal want's to upload something in this folder (private file system) - that's a really weird problem: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30113/configuring-the-temporary-directory - tried all of this but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Go to Configuration -> Media -> File system (/admin/config/media/file-system) and click "Save configuration" button. If some of paths is not writable it's field will get red border (outline). Make sure that all required paths are writable.

Also read instruction bellow every path field.